# Finding a method names using a regular expression

Tags: regex

Given stack trace generated by a .NET program how would I extract all method names appearing in the stack trace.

For example:

Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at WindowsApplication1.Program.Baz()
   at WindowsApplication1.Program.Foo()
   at WindowsApplication1.Program.Bar()
   at WindowsApplication1.Program.Main()

The output should be:

WindowsApplication1.Program.Baz
WindowsApplication1.Program.Foo
WindowsApplication1.Program.Bar
WindowsApplication1.Program.Main

Answer (score 1):

The following will match any sequence of non-space characters that is followed by `()`

```
\S+(?=\(\))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[\w.]+(?=\(\))
```

Use this regular expressiong should do what you want perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Use this regular expression: `` (?<name>[\w|\.|=|`]+)(?=\() ``

Per each stack frame it will match all characters appearing before the first parenthesis in each line

Comment: Your regex doesn't really make sense. You will include `|` and `\`` as a valid character of method name. You probably mean `[\w.=]`?